# Swift: How to reduce duplicated code when using ViewControllers with identifical buttons

Tags: swift

I have the following code on Swift:

```
class ResenhaMarcasFocinhoController: UIViewController {
    
var rotateMaisButton:UIButton! = nil
var rotateMenosButton:UIButton! = nil
var lixeiraButton:UIButton! = nil
var confirmarButton:UIButton! = nil
var desfazerVermelhoButton:UIButton! = nil
var desfazerPretoButton:UIButton! = nil

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    inflateView()
}

func inflateView() {
    rotateMaisButton = SubViewHelper.getButtonByText(buttonText: "rotate_mais", currentView: view)
    rotateMaisButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(rotateMais_Clicked), for: .touchUpInside)
    rotateMenosButton = SubViewHelper.getButtonByText(buttonText: "rotate_menos", currentView: view)
    rotateMenosButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(rotateMenos_Clicked), for: .touchUpInside)
    lixeiraButton = SubViewHelper.getButtonByText(buttonText: "lixeira", currentView: view)
    lixeiraButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(lixeira_Clicked), for: .touchUpInside)
    confirmarButton = SubViewHelper.getButtonByText(buttonText: "confirmar", currentView: view)
    confirmarButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(confirmar_Clicked), for: .touchUpInside)
    desfazerVermelhoButton = SubViewHelper.getButtonByText(buttonText: "desfazer_vermelho", currentView: view)
    desfazerVermelhoButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(desfazerVermelho_Clicked), for: .touchUpInside)
    desfazerPretoButton = SubViewHelper.getButtonByText(buttonText: "desfazer_preto", currentView: view)
    desfazerPretoButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(desfazerPreto_Clicked), for: .touchUpInside)
 }

func rotateMais_Clicked(sender: UIButton) {
    // some code
}
func rotateMenos_Clicked(sender: UIButton) {
    // some code
}
func lixeira_Clicked(sender: UIButton) {
    // some code
}
func confirmar_Clicked(sender: UIButton) {
    // some code
}
func desfazerVermelho_Clicked(sender: UIButton) {
    // some code
}
func desfazerPreto_Clicked(sender: UIButton) {
    // some code
}
```

}

The function *SubViewHelper.getButtonByText* is only a way to assign the button based in the text.

But my problem here is that I have 4 UIViewControllers that contains the same code, because each UIView has the same buttons.

Is it possible to reduce the code on each view controller?

Comment: Inherit one base view controller.

Comment: View controllers don't have to be entire screens. Wrap these buttons into a single view, with a vc, and then use an instance of that view wherever you need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ViewControllers are just classes, and they can participate in inheritance just like any class.  So define a base ViewController

```swift
class BaseViewController: UIViewController
{
// Common implementation
}
```

and then inherit from it:

```swift
class ViewController1: BaseViewController {
    ...
}
class ViewController2: BaseViewController {
    ...
}
...
```

You can call `super` for the common code.

An alternative approach would be to define a protocol for your view controllers and provide the common implementation in a protocol extension, however since extensions can't store properties, this might not be the best use for protocols.

If you prefer to use composition rather than inheritance, you can put your common code in a separate class that's not even a view controller that you instantiate in your view controllers, and forward whatever you like to it.   This is essentially creating your own kind of delegate:

```swift
struct MyViewControllerDelegate // Doesn't have to be a class so I made this a struct
{
    /* all those common buttons go here */
    func viewDidLoad() { /* common code */ }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController
{
    var myDelegate = MyViewControllerDelegate()

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        myDelegate.viewDidLoad()

        // whatever special code you need here.
    }
    ...
}
```

If you find this cropping up for other sets of view controllers, you might be able to define a protocol for your "ViewControllerDelegates" so they provide a common interface.  That would make it easier to generalize the solution.

Comment: I will try to use your example.

Comment: You can also use composition.  I updated my answer to include it.

Comment: Inheritance is really limited, you're likely going to paint yourself into a corner if you go that way. I can just imagine seeing a question in two days "how do I inherit from 2 classes at once" heh

Comment: That's why I updated to provide a compositional option, although for a given app, inheritance might be fine.

Comment: @ChipJarred I use composition in my code. I was unable to use a struct due to a problem with the addTarget method that requires a class to add the objc annotation. I just use a class without UIViewController inheritance and it works perfectly for me. I can create big new UIViewControllers using a small piece of code. Thank you very much for this solution.

Comment: @fabiobh I'm glad it was helpful!